# Is it possible to filter list of substrings by another list of strings in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, numpy

To filter list of strings by another list of strings in Python we can use the following code:

```
result = [x for x in strings1 if x in strings2]
```

But how can we filter list of substrings by another list of strings? For example:

```
substrings = ['a', 'b', 'c']
strings = ['_b_', '_c_', '_d_']
```

Result should be:

```
result = ['b', 'c']
```

Comment: with a simple list comprehension: `[i for i in substrings for j in strings if i in j]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like that:

```
[x for x in substrings if [y for y in strings if x in y]]
```

```
In [1]: substrings = ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [2]: strings = ['_b_', '_c_', '_d_']

In [3]: [x for x in substrings if [y for y in strings if x in y]]
Out[3]: ['b', 'c']
```

Comment: Was trying to use this in one of my function, but it gives TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' . Could you suggest a solution

Answer (score 3):

Elegant way to achieve this is via using [**`any`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) with a *list comprehension* as:

```
>>> substrings = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> my_strings = ['_b_', '_c_', '_d_']

>>> [s for s in substrings if any(s in i for i in my_strings)]
['b', 'c']
```

Here `any` will return `True` if any of string in `substrings` is present as substring in `my_strings`. As soon as it finds the match, it will short-circuit the iteration (without checking for other matches) and will return the result as `True`. Due to the short-circuiting property of `any`, it won't make the unnecessary iteration across the entire list, resulting in better performance.