# How to filter a list by using another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have these two lists:

```
my_targets = ["aa1","bb2"]
my_list = ["aa1_rtc","aa1fp","aar1","bb","bb2_11"]
```

How can I select only those entries from `my_list` that contain any of `my_targets`. Please notice that `aa1_rtc` and `aa1fp` contain `aa1`, while `aar1` should be filtered out.

```
final_list = [i for i in my_list if i in my_targets]
len(final_list)
```

Expected result:

final_list =

```
["aa1_rtc","aa1fp","bb2_11"]
```

Comment: Why downvoted???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Substring filter list elements by another list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55135461/substring-filter-list-elements-by-another-list-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with `any` for this:

```
[i for i in my_list if any(j in i for j in my_targets)]
# ['aa1_rtc', 'aa1fp', 'bb2_11']
```

Comment: Could you please upvote my question? Someone downvoted it for unclear reason.